# Compose beta01 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to realize group twice

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am migrating to Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-beta01 and I am encountering a compiler crash.
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to realize group twice`
the logs are pretty obscure and nothing seems to point the our code. Has anyone encountered something similar or has an idea how I could find the source of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue when compile a code with @Composable function in forEach lambda of collection of Any elements. Something like this

```
listOf(1f, 2.0, 4L, 0).forEach {
    Text("value: $it")
}
```

So check your code for this bottleneck.

Comment: this is actually an answer, 
btw (2..15).forEach doesnt work too! 
U need to use it like (2..15).toList{}.forEach